# object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

I have a form to add new Appartments, and in this form I have a dropdown where the user can choose what Person is responsible.

Apparantly my application thinks that the Person is modified when you select from the dropdown and try to save the Appartment. And it gives me the error below indicating i should save the Person first. But the Person is not modified. It is only the Appartment that should be saved with a reference to a different Person.

`object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging`

How can I make my application understand that the Person himself has not been modified. Only the Appartment?

Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Appartment")
public class Appartment{
    ....
    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name = "client_contact_person_id")
    private Person clientResponsiblePerson;
}
```

The action loads all Persons into a List responsiblePersons.

And the JSP:

```
<s:select name="appartment.clientResponsiblePerson.id" list="responsiblePersons"
        listKey="id" listValue="fullName" headerKey="-1"
        label="%{getText('appartment.clientContact.ourContact')}" headerValue="%{getText('person.choose')}"
        required="true" cssClass="select medium" />
```

Any ideas? I've been searching and debugging for hours without any solution... :(

UPDATE:
Steven suggested that i remove the id from `appartment.clientResponsiblePerson.id`. This is a reasonable suggestion. I did just try it, but then it seems like my Application dont know how to map the value submitted by the form to a Person-object. As im setting `listKey="id"` the value submitted is the Person's ID.

I recieve the following errors: 
`Invalid field value for field "appartment.clientResponsiblePerson".`

`tag 'select', field 'list', name 'appartment.clientResponsiblePerson': The requested list key 'responsiblePeople' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]`

So my initial thought was that maybe i should delete the listKey and listValue from my s:select. Maybe struts automagically detects the id from the object and uses toString for value? But I tried this as well without any more luck.

Another really strange thing is that I do the exact same thing in another form. In that form i am selecting Areas from a dropdown. And I am using appartment.area.id for name. And it works perfectly there. Strange.. I also checked that the Area - Appartment reference was not set up to automaticly persist or merge.

It strikes me that what i am trying to achive should be really straigh forward. What is it that i am not getting here?

Comment: The message you posted as part of your update means that the value passed to the list attribute (responsiblePersons) is not a "collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator". You should not be getting that error unless you changed the getResponsiblePersons() method on your action or you changed the value of the list attribute on your s:select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apparantly my application thinks that the Person is modified when you select from the dropdown and try to save the Appartment.

That's exactly what your code is doing. The following line is the culprit:

```
appartment.clientResponsiblePerson.id
```

That is telling the Struts2 framework to take the id of the person you selected in your drop down and pass it to `getAppartment().getClientResponsiblePerson().setId(id)`. That doesn't change to a new responsible person, it changes the primary key for the existing person. Calling setClientResponsiblePerson(Person) would change the person.

Try using `appartment.clientResponsiblePerson` instead and see how that works for you.

**Update**

> Another really strange thing is that I do the exact same thing in another form.

I don't see how that would work either.

Struts2 doesn't know what a `Person` is, so you have a few options:

1. Create a type converter to tell Struts2 how to convert from "1" (or whatever is passed in from your dropdown) to an instance of a Person.
2. Add a `setPerson(Integer)` method on your action which will look up the appropriate Person entity based on the Integer primary key passed in and then update your s:select to `<s:select name="person" list="responsiblePersons" .../>`

Personally, I use #1.

Comment: thanks for your answers. Just tried it and it got me another new error. Please see my updated answer for more detail.

Comment: Please provide the updated code for your s:select. You do still need the listKey and listValue, those drive what is in the drop down and have nothing to do with what Struts2 does on the backend.

Comment: Thanks for your update Steven. I'll give this a shot as soon as i get time and post results back. But i think you just gave me the solution i was missing :) Dunno why the other form works though.. but thats a differnt story.